# How to verify self-signed certificate?

Tags: perl, ssl, ssl-certificate, io-socket-ssl

I use `Net::Jabber::Client` to send messages via XMPP.

The server I am connecting to uses self-signed certificate:

```
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2853: new ctx 45728400
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1540: start handshake
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:717: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:750: using SNI with hostname my.host.name
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:785: request OCSP stapling
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:806: set socket to non-blocking to enforce timeout=10
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:819: call Net::SSLeay::connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:822: done Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:832: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:842: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:862: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:819: call Net::SSLeay::connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2754: did not get stapled OCSP response
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2707: ok=0 [0] /CN=my.host.name/CN=my.host.name
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:822: done Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:825: SSL connect attempt failed

DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:825: local error: SSL connect attempt failed error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:828: fatal SSL error: SSL connect attempt failed error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1963: downgrading SSL only, not closing socket
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2875: free ctx 45728400 open=
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2879: free ctx 45728400 callback
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2886: OK free ctx 45728400
```

I have found that I can pass `SSL_fingerprint` and/or `SSL_verifycn_name` to pass verification of self-signed certificate.

To make it just work I hack [this](https://metacpan.org/source/DAPATRICK/XML-Stream-1.24/lib/XML/Stream.pm#L635)

```
my %ssl_params = (
    SSL_verify_mode => $self->{SIDS}->{newconnection}->{ssl_verify},
    SSL_hostname    => 'my.host.name',
    SSL_verifycn_name => 'my.host.name',
);
```

without success =(

I try to use `->get_fingerprint` to obtain finger print and pass it to `SSL_fingerprint` parameter, but:

```
IO::Socket::SSL->start_SSL(
    $self->{SIDS}->{$sid}->{sock},
    $self->{SIDS}->{$sid}->{ssl_params}
) or die "$IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_ERROR";
```

fail with error:

```
SSL connect attempt failed error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed at
```

Which option to pass to `IO::Socket::SSL` to verify self-signed certificate?

Comment: Try with `SSL_ca_path`/`SSL_ca_file` to set things with the specific certificate you get (but you will have to maintain that each time it changes). The checks on hostname happens after the CA check. You may see people advising to remove any checks with `SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE` but that would be a very dangerous idea, so not to follow.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek How is that more dangerous than trusting self-signed certificates?

Comment: @melpomene The difference between trusting **one** specific certificate that you **specifically** added in your code/configuration (after having made sure it is the correct one) and trusting **any** random certificate that you know nothing about. TLS provides multiple guarantees and while people concentrate on integrity, in fact authentication is more important. Which is why removing any kind of authentication is almost always a bad idea, as in the end you can have an hypersecure confidential connection... to some endpoint that is not the one you think you connect to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the fingerprint is probably the easiest way to verify a self-signed certificate which is in your own control. When using `SSL_fingerprint` it will not care about any other kind of validations, i.e. not check the name, revocation, expiration etc anymore - so if you want to have checks for this too you should not use `SSL_fingerprint`.

Getting the fingerprint of a site can be done by connecting to the site once without validation (since you have no trust in the certificate yet) and getting the fingerprint  or by getting the fingerprint from the certificate directly.

To get the fingerprint by asking the server, assuming that the connection is not intercepted so that you get the correct fingerprint:

```
use IO::Socket::SSL;
print IO::Socket::SSL->new(
    PeerHost => 'example.com:443',
    # switch off validation since the certificate is not trusted yet
    SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE,
)->get_fingerprint,"\n";
```

This currently gives `sha256$642de54d84c30494157f53f657bf9f89b4ea6c8b16351fd7ec258d556f821040` which can be directly used as argument for `SSL_fingerprint`.

If you have instead the certificate for the site already you can compute the fingerprint directly on it:

```
# get the certificate
$ openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -servername example.com 
...
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIF8jCCBNqgAwIBAgIQDmTF+8I2reFLFyrrQceMsDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBw
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

# take this PEM certificate and get fingerprint
$ openssl x509 -fingerprint -sha256 -noout -in cert.pem
SHA256 Fingerprint=64:2D:E5:4D:84:C3:04:94:15:7F:53:F6:57:BF:9F:89:B4:EA:6C:8B:16:35:1F:D7:EC:25:8D:55:6F:82:10:40
```

The shown fingerprint is practically the same as before, only written in a different way. By removing all ':' (which are only there for readability) one gets `642DE5....1040` and by prefixing it with the used hash algorithm `sha256` one gets something to be usable in `SSL_fingerprint`: `sha256$642DE5...1040`.

To use the fingerprint then to connect to the site:

```
my $cl = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
    PeerHost => 'example.com:443',
    SSL_fingerprint => 'sha256$642DE5...1040'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`IO::Socket::SSL` can verify self signed certificate only if it trusts the certificate authority file that you use to [self sign the certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297139/how-do-you-sign-a-certificate-signing-request-with-your-certification-authority/21340898#21340898).

I think you need to pass proper `SSL_ca_file` or `SSL_ca_path` to `IO::Socket::SSL` so that certificate authority file is accessible to it. This is the first thing mentioned in [common usage errors](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL#Common-Usage-Errors) section of `IO::Socket::SSL` docs.

Comment: yes, but How to get cert's pubkey and save it locally If I only have access to host:port of service. To trust this self-signed certificate I can [pine](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning#What_Is_Pinning.3F) it by set [`SSL_fingerprint`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL#SSL_fingerprint). But connection, as you can see, is not established: `SSL connect attempt failed`. today hoster give me pubkey and its finger print: `SHA256 Fingerprint=E0:3F:F1:4E:06:18:F7:93:34:6F:91:77:7F:C0:9E:3A:CF:93:F5:BC:12:71:38:30:AC:87:5E:21:7E:CB:7A:58`

Comment: But this format is differ from `IO::Socket::SSL` module format.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368123/how-to-extract-the-root-ca-and-subordinate-ca-from-a-certificate-chain-in-linux might help you in extracting the certificate authority files from the web service. I searched google for "get ca file from website".

Comment: Otherwise you can try using something like `SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE`, which might make things work. In this mode communication will be encrypted but it will not verify the identity of the server that it is talking with, so impersonation or man-in-the-middle attacks may not be detected.

Comment: Thanks. I have found the way how to extract cert. As you can see the fingerprint format is not suitable for IO::Socket::SSL module. I convert it manually =(

Answer (score 0):

Typically this occurs when encrypting via localhost, where a certificate per se hardly plays a role.

Modules that involve IO::Socket::SSL can be used with an additional parameter to prevent crashing with "certificate verify failed".

To solve that issue in the long-term, at the top, add this line:

```
use IO::Socket::SSL qw(SSL_VERIFY_NONE);

$smtp = Net::SMTPS->new('localhost',
   doSSL => 'starttls',
   Port => 587,
   SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE
);
```